# Python Matlab Engine Install

Tags: python, matlab

Ive been trying to install matlab engine for python so I can call matlab functions from within my python scripts.

The guide Im using is this one: http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/install-the-matlab-engine-for-python.html

It says the setup.py file is located in matlabroot\extern\engines\python, however, my extern folder does not contain an engines folder (only examples, include, lib)

Am I looking in the wrong place? Or is there another way to get this installed? Im using matlab 2012b and python 2.7 if that makes a difference

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looking at the release notes for Matlab 2014, the Python engine didn't exist until R2014b, so I don't think you'll be able to use it in 2012.

http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/release-notes.html

Comment: You can use python-matlab-bridge instead.