# Matlab API installed but no module in Python 3.6

Tags: matlab, python-3.6

Hi i am having the issue of installing Matlab API but the module is not defined when i run it. I am using Python 3.6 and Matlab 2017b. is there anyway i can get this function working without needing to change the version? Build and install is in my project folder. I also tried installing the API in python root but it doesnt seem to work too.

Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Matlab Engine Install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27772334/python-matlab-engine-install)

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply! But mine is not a duplicate of the question. I am using matlab 2017 and python 3.6 so should have such an issue?